# How to set default value for FloatField in django model

Tags: python, mysql, django

How can I set a default value for `FloatField` in django.

Initially when I had created the model and declared the float field as:

```
cost = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

and db also created successfully through south migration.

But now when I am trying to do edit on that field using the html form, and no value is entered in the cost field, in the form  its throwing `value error`.
Thus I think if I can set a default value for cost field it may fix the problem.

But I don't know how to set a default value for `FloatField` in `django`.

Comment: Doesn't `cost = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0.0)` work?

Comment: May we assume that you would like to display something like "None" or "Free" for items that have no cost? I.e. a default of 0.0 will not suffice?

Answer (score 21):

Your code should work. Perhaps something is setting the empty value to a non-null value (like an empty string). I'd have to see the full error message.

Since this is an old thread, I'm going to post the answer to the question I came here for, **"How do you set FloatField default to Null in the database?"**

```
cost = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

Answer (score 10):

Float Field is quite related to Decimal Field so, probably it should take a default argument. Try doing this..

```
cost = models.FloatField(default=to_some_value)
```

Comment: If you are giving a `default` value you don't need to set `null` and `blank` attributes